How to save a file received in an ASP.NET Core Web API to a file server with specific credentials
I have a server called MySERVER with a share called TPLFOTOS. I have another server in running an ASP.NET Core Web API that receives an image and has to save it to \\MySERVER\MySavedFiles.
The image is sent correctly, the web service receives it OK, and when it tries to save it, I get the following error:

Error when writing file Access to the path '\MySERVER\MySavedFiles\20231101\010067498420231101132440.jpg' is denied.

I need to tell which user should be use to connect to the shared resource and save the file under that user, or how should I do this?
This is how I'm trying to write the received file into the remote file server:
private async Task WriteFile(IFormFile file)
{   
    string fileName;
    string pathUploads;

    try
    {
        fileName = file.FileName;
        pathUploads = @"\\MySERVER\MySavedFiles\20231101";
    
        var pathFile = Path.Combine(pathUploads, fileName);  

        using (var stream = new FileStream(pathFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error al escribir archivo " + e.Message);
        //log error
    }

    return;
}


Run your application using an account that has permissions instead, or give the app's account the necessary permissions. That's how all clouds services and Windows work. There's no username/password in Windows authentication. Resources are accessed using the user's account, in this case the account that executes the web app. This way there's no chance of leaked credentials

a webapi receives the file, that runs under the Application pool with identity=ApplicationPoolIdentity  how should I give permissions to a remote file server?

Change the application pool's account to a domain account with the necessary permissions

I have done that, I am using an account in the apppool that is in the local administrators of the webserver and is part of IIS_USER, that account has write access to the file server, but it still does not work, what permissions should I check?

Have you tried reading the docs? This isn't obscure knowledge, it's how IIS and ASP.NET work since 2000. It's very well documented and explained in all the books and courses, because using the correct account is fundamental when you deploy to production. IIS_USER that's not a domain account so it can't access anything outside the web server.
